# Please exlpain the following while initializing a class in java

Tags: java

```
class Size{
Size(){

}
//public  final Size SMALL = new Size();//infinite loop
  final Size as = new Size();//infinite loop
//static Size aw = new Size();//No infinte loop

}


class b{

static public void main(String ftr[]){

    Size z = new Size();

  }
}
```

when static Size aw is equal to  new Size(); there is error when above program is run.
See the scenario below, when the program is run with:

```
  public  final Size SMALL = new Size();// infinite loop is happening 
  final Size as = new Size();
```

an infinite loop is happening and program is giving

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
  at Size.<init>(Interesting.java:6)  
  at Size.<init>(Interesting.java:6)
```

Can somebody explain to me or, point me to the places where I can find the reason behind    this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `as` in line 6 is an *instance attribute* ( part of the object )  so you can read it like this:

> *To create this object I have to first create this object of type Size, but to create that object I have to create first the object of type size, but to create...*

Hence inifinite loop.

In the ohter hand when you mark it with the `static` qualifier, you make it a *class attribute* ( part of the class not of the object )  so you can read it like.

> *To define this class, I have to create this object of type Size*

Then Java says... "ok, got it, I'll do with then the time comes". The class definition is created and when loaded a new instance of that class is created. No confusion nor infinite loop arise.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

```
final Size as = new Size();
```

`as` is an instance variable, so every instance of `Size` has it. The constructor of `Size` invokes `as = new Size()`, thus creating a new instance of `Size`, which in its turn will also start the constructor and invokes `as = new Size()` .... resulting in infinite recursive constructor invokations.

The main point here is to notice that since `as` is an instance variable, every time an object is created - it is initialized in the constructor.

You might want to make `as` a class variable, by declaring it `static`. This will cause the initialization of `as` to happen only once and prevent the infinite constructor invokation.

Answer (score 0):

static = one object in the entire application, so it gets created once and that's it.
non-static = one instance per object you create, how many objects are you creating? Well you create z and then inside z you create a new z, that creates a new z....